# Is there a way to using Processing with Pyodide in Python Mode?

Tags: processing, p5.js, pyodide

I'm trying to write Processing graphics programs in Python that run in a web browser that I can then copy into a script on my local machine and run them with [py5](https://py5coding.org/index.html). I haven't been able to find a Processing package that uses Python Mode that runs in a web context. They all seem to use the [p5.js methods](https://p5js.org/get-started/) such as `createCanvas` rather than `size`.

The closest I have found is [ProcessingJS](https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js) which does use Python Mode and is used by [Skulpt](https://skulpt.org/) and [Trinket](https://trinket.io/) but the library is now deprecated. I also tried installing [py5](https://py5coding.org/index.html) in Pyodide but there's no Pyodide-compatible wheel for JPype so that won't work. I also found [an issue](https://github.com/berinhard/pyp5js/issues/45) in the [pyp5js](https://github.com/berinhard/pyp5js) project which attempted to translate function names but [the code](https://gist.github.com/villares/1b14997beef52de34069b91752faef40) is a proof of concept.

[This table](https://abav.lugaralgum.com/Resources-for-teaching-programming/#processing--python-tools-table) I found seems to list the available options but none meet my use case. I also found [this video](https://dl.acm.org/action/downloadSupplement?doi=10.1145%2F3532836.3536231&file=dtppl_presentation.mp4) helpful for understanding the current landscape of processing libraries.

Comment: The alternative for Pyodide is [Wasmer SDK](https://wasmer.io/posts/introducing-the-wasmer-js-sdk) which claims better legacy CPython compatibility with various hacks, like threads and file system. It might or might not work for your use case better.

Comment: Thanks, I tried out Wasmer SDK but it seemed to take ~9 seconds to load on localhost and that's before I installed any python packages. I also don't think any of the native python Processing libraries would work with a HTML web environment because they output to a GUI on the desktop.

Comment: They say they use asyncify, which is probably why it's so slow. asyncify generally makes code like 3x slower and 4x bigger. Unfortunately since they are using it to implement fork, not even JavaScript Promise Integration can save them since that has an opaque stack.